# LocalDate.parse fails for DateTimeFormatter with multiple patterns

Tags: java, kotlin, parsing, localdate, kotest

You can create a `DateTimeFormatter` with multiple patterns using the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, but `LocalDate.parse` doesn't seem to like it. It works with a single pattern and fails with mutliple ones.

```kotlin
    test("can parse dates") {
        val formatter =
            DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("dd/MM/yy")
                .appendPattern("dd/MM/yyyy") // <-- fine when commented out
                .appendPattern("yyyy/MM/dd") // <-- fine when commented out
                .toFormatter()
        // error: Text '12/12/21' could not be parsed at index 8
        LocalDate.parse("12/12/21", formatter) shouldBe LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 12)
        
        // works just fine
        LocalDate.parse("12/12/21", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy")) shouldBe LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 12)
    }
```

Is there a way to make it work or do I have to use `Regex` to first figure out which pattern I need and then use it for parsing?

Comment: You may need to read up on what `appendPattern` does, because it doesn't add _alternatives_, it extends the pattern of the builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a comment already explained, `appendPattern` adds to what the date format string wants. So, your date formatter would format today (november 18th 2023) as:

```
18/11/2318/11/20232023/11/18
```

And would be identical to:

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("dd/MM/yydd/MM/yyyyyyyy/MM/dd");
```

In general you can't just have DTF represent multiple conflicting alternatives. It does have *some* functionality for this - patterns can be placed in `[]` which marks them as optional. For example:

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("yyyy[-]MM[-]dd");
```

will both parse `20231118` and `2023-11-18` (and formats as `2023-11-18`).

But you can't use that to parse the 3 different formats you pasted. Because your formats **are ambiguous**.

This:

`23/11/18` - is that 23rd of november 2018, or is it 23rd of november 18 (yes, 18 - as in, over 2000 years ago. It's still a valid date!), or is it November 18th in the year 23 (Still a valid date?)

You presumably consider any date prior to the year 1000 to be 'invalid', or at least as something that must be rendered as 0001 for example, so you might be able to do something nutty with optional markers, but that's not really what it is for.

Regexp it is. Regexp to figure out what format it is in, then DTF to parse that into a `LocalDate` object.